# Always create UNIQUE ID without using database - PHP

Tags: php

I have I have static HTML / JS page without any database (I don't need it). However I start fight with some issue. I need to generate random ID which have to be unique(used once and never ever again).

**Stardard MySQL way:**

On standard application I will do it with storing all used IDs in database
and when needed new one I will simply

```
// I generate ID here, let's say it's 123
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table WHERE id = 123
```

**My solution which may be not the best one:**

I am thinking alternative may be some storing in file

```
// Let's generate ID here, and make it 123 again

    $handle = fopen("listOfIDs.txt", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        $used = false;
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            if($line = 123) {
              $used = true;
              break;
          }
        }        
        fclose($handle);
        return $used;
    } else {
        // error opening the file.
    }
```

Dispite the fact I can imagine my option may work it could be super slow when file become bigger.

**Question:**

What's the best way to keep simple unique IDs without using database.

Edit:
I forgot to mentioned that unique ID have to be numbers only.

Comment: use `uniqid()` php function :)

Comment: you could just store the last used id and increment by 1?

Comment: md5(time()); and then check if id is used

Comment: plus you're not LOCKING the file, so potentially 2+ script instances can be processing it at the same time and end up with the same ID.

Comment: @JOUM, from the manual: "**Warning** This function does not guarantee uniqueness of return value" :)

Comment: @Dekel Yep, you are right.  `uniqid().substr(str_shuffle(time()),0,4)`

Comment: @JOUM guys, why not using microtime?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for answers, just to note i added edit in my question because I didnt say at start that ID have to be number only.

Comment: What will you use these numbers for? Knowing that will help us understand "how unique" (I know, that's a slightly weird phrase!) you need the numbers to be.

Comment: note one more thing... your file wouldn't need to be that big because you could use IDs with time() prefixes and remove all older than 10 seconds or something alike.

Comment: Hi @MattGibson I generate number of order. Each order is specific and contains specific items.

Answer (score 1):

You could use uniqid(), str_rand(something), timestamp, some hash with random data that you probably never get twice.

Or, doing your way, you could have a single line with information in this file, just the last used id:

```
$fp = fopen("lastID.txt", "r+");

if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  // lock the file
    $lastId = fgets($fp);   // get last id
    $newId = $lastId +1;    //update the id
    ftruncate($fp, 0);      // truncate file
    fwrite($fp, $newId);    //write the new Id
    fflush($fp);            // flush output
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock
} else {
    throw new Exception("Could not get the lock");
}

fclose($fp);

return $newId;
```

Comment: locking the file would slow things down significantly, but it would need to be done because two users could open at the same time, so your uniqueness would come down to randomness... still pretty good, but not determinate.

Comment: SQLite would make it better :)

Comment: I try it your way @FelippeDuarte because it looks nice however `echo $lastId` will return me always `1`. Any idea where can be an issue?

Comment: I found out it won't work because it can't calculate `$lastId + 1`  while `$lastId` contains hexa chars from file which will be automaticly add.

Comment: This file should only contains the last id. Ony 1 line with some number, like 1, 2, 45, 1267 and so on... Why do you have hexa chars?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a mix of the current timestamp, the request ip, and a randomnumber:

```
$unique = microtime().$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'].rand(0,9999);
```

Sure theorically you can get a request that executes this operation in the same microtime, with the same remote host, and matching the random number, but it's almost impossible, I think.

Comment: no one said it's being executed on web server :D. i do like the microtime()

Comment: you can add a str_replace in the remote host part to leave only numbers.

Comment: Note that if you don't have the request IP—and if your code is generating a static website, presumably you don't—this approach is pretty much equivalent to `uniqid` with the `more_entropy` flag, only it won't be as unique. And bear in mind that some OSes (Windows, perhaps?) won't give you the microseconds.

Comment: sorry, REMOTE_ADDR or something potentially unique per user

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP `uniqid` with `$more_entropy = true`, which **increases** the likelihood that the result will be unique.

```
$id = uniqid("", true);
```

You can also work some random number out using current date and time, etc. You should consider how fast the users may generate these numbers, if it's super fast, there might be a possibility of two different users generating the same $id because it happened at the same time.